# Spring boot Design Patterns and SSR vs REST api got a few questions

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, design-patterns, server-side-rendering

i would like to ask a few questions about building spring boot 2 applications.So few months ago i decided to start building basic blog app with spring boot and angular, I've made a few entities, rest controllers for users, roles, articles, categories and comments, made a service and service implementation for each, for example my UserServiceImpl looked like this
using HQL, not repositories.

```
@Override
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        Query q = entityManager.createQuery("select u from User u");
        List<User> users = q.getResultList();

        if(users == null){
            users = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        return users;
    }
```

Is this the right way to do it? Do i have to build it like that ,because I didn't used any repo's  and every spring-boot-best-practices project I saw was using repositories instead of HQL and I'm not really sure should i use repositories or custom services with HQL. I am totally lost with that.This is my first question.

The second question is should I use server side rendering and api or i should use only api without server side rendering, because i saw a few projects made with ssr and rest api's which confused me a lot.

Thanks for the help provided

Answer (score 1):

**Answer 1** :

There are 3 popular repositories `CRUDRepository`, `PagingAndSortingRepository` and `JpaRepository`.

1. JpaRepository is an abstraction layer from Spring Jpa to EntityManager
2. What you are using is HQL with `EntityManager`. You can use HQL in EntityManager and `JPQL` in JpaRepository.
3. Using `JpaRepository` your code becomes just this

   List users=userRepository.findAll();
   return users;
4. You can achieve similar thing using JPQL that can be achieved with EntityManagers using `@Query` annotation.
5. **Importantly** it depends on the team which you'll be part of and what they are working on. Mostly in corporate world, teams uses **older** technologies for mainly the following Reasons

   - **They are stable**
   - **Documentation/Help for older technologies are many** (older doesn't mean JDBC etc. it means, relatively old releases / technologies)
   - **Most of the applications will be compatible with them**

So, it is not **BEST PRACTICE** to use Repositories - in my opinion!

**Answer 2**:

1. The advantage of server side rendering is, on the server you've more resource using which you can render the response faster.

   - Browsers / Client Devices may not be fast enough and they take relatively more time to convert your JSON/XML.
   - When you get rendered response from server itself, JS Engine just have to display and not bother about converting your JSON to HTML/CSS and Render on cliend device.

Comment: Great answer, appreciate it really.I forgot to mention about the project structure can you give me any project examples? Once again thanks for the great answer!